# Переключение между вкладками

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как сделать переключение при нажатии на кнопку в другую кнопку на примере данного кода т.е. присутствует на одной вкладке кнопка при нажатии которой из вкладки основа переходит на вкладку дополнительно.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
First_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab = QTabWidget()
tab.addTab(First_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Основа")  # вкладки
Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab.addTab(Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Дополнительно")
button_1 = QPushButton('Далее',First_frame_of_the_Right_frame)
button_1.resize(100, 40)
button_1.move(0, 0)
hbox1.addWidget(tab)
root.setLayout(hbox1)
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `1.` Не нужно экономить байты в скрипте жертвуя читаемостью кода `2.` Пользуйтесь layout, т.к. resize и move виджетов внутри других виджетов плохой тон `3.` В питоне с большой буквы только классы пишутся, поэтому лучше придерживаться общего стиля. Покажу наглядно в ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создание виджета с двумя вкладками и с примером переключения между ними:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Tab example')

        # Обработка сигнала через метод
        self.button_next = QPushButton('Далее')
        self.button_next.clicked.connect(self._on_next_tab_clicked)

        # Обработка сигнала через лямбду
        self.button_prev = QPushButton('Назад')
        self.button_prev.clicked.connect(lambda: self.tab.setCurrentIndex(0))

        tab_1 = QFrame()
        layout_tab_1 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_tab_1.addWidget(self.button_next)
        tab_1.setLayout(layout_tab_1)

        tab_2 = QFrame()
        layout_tab_2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_tab_2.addWidget(self.button_prev)
        tab_2.setLayout(layout_tab_2)

        self.tab = QTabWidget()
        self.tab.addTab(tab_1, "Основа")
        self.tab.addTab(tab_2, "Дополнительно")

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_next_tab_clicked(self):
        self.tab.setCurrentIndex(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    root = Widget()
    root.resize(400, 200)
    root.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот так выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Функция **`tab.setCurrentIndex(1)`** задает переключение между вкладками

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


def clikedselect():
    tab.setCurrentIndex(1)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
First_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab = QTabWidget()
tab.addTab(First_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Основа")  # вкладки
Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab.addTab(Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Дополнительно")
button_1 = QPushButton('Далее',First_frame_of_the_Right_frame)
button_1.resize(100, 40)
button_1.move(0, 0)
button_1.clicked.connect(clikedselect)
hbox1.addWidget(tab)
root.setLayout(hbox1)
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```